# Right angle link style in a d3.js hierarchical tree

Tags: javascript, web, d3.js, graph

I am trying to render a simple hierarchical tree using d3.js.

I can find a lot of code example of such tree, but none of them have the style of links that I want.

This example is fine for my needs, but I can't manage to display everything vertically with right-angle turn: https[:]//codepen.io/zhulinpinyu/pen/EaZrmM

How can I change this to fit the following layout ?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an [indented tree](https://www.google.com/search?q=d3%20indented%20tree).

See below, based on this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025):

```js
const margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20}
const width = 960;
const barHeight = 20;
const barWidth = (width - margin.left - margin.right) * 0.8;
const duration = 400;
let i = 0;
let root;

const elbow = d => `M${d.source.y},${d.source.x} V${d.target.x} H${d.target.y}`;

const color = d => d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";

const update = (source) => {

  // Compute the flattened node list
  const nodes = root.descendants();

  const height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  d3.select("svg").transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("height", height);

  // Compute the layout
  root.eachBefore((n, i) => {
    n.x = i * barHeight;
    n.y = n.depth * 40;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, d => d.id || (d.id = ++i));

  const nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.y0},${source.x0})`)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .on("click", click);
      
  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .style("fill", d => d.children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff");
      
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 3.5)
    .attr("dx", d => 10 + d.depth)
    .text(d => d.data.name);
    
  // update
  var nodeUpdate = node.merge(nodeEnter)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration);
    
  nodeUpdate
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`);

  nodeUpdate
    .attr("r", 7)
    .style("fill", d => d.children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff");
    
  nodeUpdate
    .select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  nodeEnter.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`)
    .style("opacity", 1);

  node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
    .style("opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.y}, ${source.x}")`)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();

  var nodeExit = node.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration);
  
  nodeExit.attr("transform", d => `translate(${source.y},${source.x})`)
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(root.links(), d => d.target.id);

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter()
    .insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", d => {
      const o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
      return elbow({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", elbow);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", elbow);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", d => {
      const o = {x: source.x, y: source.y, parent: {x: source.x, y: source.y}};
      return elbow({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  root.each(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

const click = (event, d) => {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

// svg
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width) 
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// initial tree
root = d3.hierarchy(data);
root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = 0;
update(root);
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
const data = {
 "name": "Visualisation tools",
 "children": [
   {
    "name": "Interactive tools",
    "free": true,
    "description": "Interactive authoring tools",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "Browser-based",
      "description": "Web-based 'cloud' applications for authoring data visualisations",
      "free": true,
      "children": [
       {
        "name": "Datawrapper",
        "description": "An open-source platform for publishing charts on the web. Cloud-based or self-hosted.",
        "url": "https://datawrapper.de/",
        "free": true
       },
       {
        "name": "Google Sheets",
        "description": "Spreadsheet in the cloud with charting",
        "free": true
       },
       {
        "name": "plotly",
        "description": "Cloud-based interactive tool for creating data visualisations",
        "url": "https://plot.ly/",
        "free": true
       },
       {
        "name": "RAW",
        "description": "Open-source interactive tool for creating and exporting D3-like charts",
        "url": "http://raw.densitydesign.org/",
        "free": true
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "name": "Desktop",
      "children": [
       {
        "name": "Tableau Desktop",
        "description": "Powerful tool for data analytics and visualisation",
        "url": "http://www.tableausoftware.com/products/desktop"
       },
       {
        "name": "Tableau Public",
        "description": "Free version of Tableau Desktop where charts are public",
        "url": "http://www.tableausoftware.com/products/public",
        "free": true
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "name": "Coding",
    "description": "Code-based data visualisation creation",
    "free": true,
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "JavaScript",
      "description": "The language behind most (all?) browser-based data visualisations",
      "free": true,
      "children": [
       {
        "name": "Charting libraries",
        "description": "Off-the-shelf pre-designed charts. Easy to use but less flexible.",
        "free": true,
        "children": [
         {
          "name": "Google Charts",
          "description": "A good selection of charts including bar, line, scatter, geo, pie, donut, org etc.",
          "url": "https://developers.google.com/chart/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "HighCharts",
          "description": "A well maintained commercial library of commonly used chart types",
          "url": "https://www.highcharts.com/"
         },
         {
          "name": "InfoVis",
          "description": "A lovely selection of charts including bar, pie, sunburst, icicle, network, trees etc.",
          "url": "https://philogb.github.io/jit/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "Mapping",
          "description": "Libraries for visualising geographic data",
          "free": true,
          "children": [
           {
            "name": "Kartograph",
            "description": "Lovely vector based mapping library with good browser support",
            "url": "http://kartograph.org/",
            "free": true
           },
           {
            "name": "Leaflet",
            "description": "Tile-based mapping library",
            "url": "http://leafletjs.com/",
            "free": true
           }
          ]
         },
         {
          "name": "MetricsGraphics.js",
          "description": "Beautiful line, scatter and histogram charts built on top of D3",
          "url": "http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "NVD3",
          "description": "A general purpose charting library built on top of D3",
          "url": "http://nvd3.org/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "Sigma",
          "description": "Library for visualising networks",
          "url": "http://sigmajs.org/",
          "free": true
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        "name": "Custom coded",
        "description": "For maximum flexibility, custom coding is the way to go. These libraries will lend a hand.",
        "free": true,
        "children": [
         {
          "name": "D3",
          "description": "The jewel in the crown of web-based data visualisation. A library packed full of components for building any data visualisation you can imagine.",
          "url": "https://d3js.org/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "Ractive",
          "description": "Relatively new, Ractive helps you make your HTML and SVG interactive",
          "url": "http://www.ractivejs.org/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "Raphaël",
          "description": "A general purpose drawing library with good browser support",
          "url": "http://raphaeljs.com/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "Snap.svg",
          "description": "A modern version of Raphaël that supports modern browsers",
          "url": "http://snapsvg.io/",
          "free": true
         },
         {
          "name": "Variance",
          "description": "A declarative, mark-up based data visualisation library",
          "url": "https://variancecharts.com/"
         },
         {
          "name": "Vega",
          "description": "A declarative language for specifying data visualistions",
          "url": "https://trifacta.github.io/vega/",
          "free": true
         }
        ]
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "name": "Other",
      "description": "Non-JavaScript languages for producing web-based data visualisations",
      "free": true,
      "children": [
       {
        "name": "Python",
        "description": "Python's a very popular language in data science and is a pleasant language to learn and use",
        "free": true,
        "children": [
         {
          "name": "Bokeh",
          "description": "A powerful tool for producing interactive plots, dashboards and data applications",
          "url": "https://bokeh.pydata.org/",
          "free": true
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        "name": "R",
        "description": "Very popular language for data science",
        "free": true,
        "children": [
         {
          "name": "Shiny",
          "description": "A platform for producing web applications using R",
          "url": "http://shiny.rstudio.com/",
          "free": true
         }
        ]
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
 ]
}</script>
```